# Is it possible to have a retina download icon for adhoc/ota distribution?

Tags: ios, plist, ad-hoc-distribution, ota

Having just discovered how to have our app icon show up during an OTA install I have learned that it is too fuzzy and we need a higher resolution icon. Find attached a version of the .plist file we are using.
 So far my research has turned up next to nothing and trying to add an "Icon57x57@2x.png" didn't work either. Is there a special key I need to add?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://downloadURI/app.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://downloadURI/Icon57x57.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <!-- metadata omitted for brevity sake -->
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a PNG file with a size of 114 x 114 px at the referenced path. No need to use any special suffix. The image will be scaled if it doesn't match exactly, but this usually works well enough, so you won't notice a large difference to the app's actual icon.

If your app is universal, you may want to put an even larger image there to support the Retina iPad's 144px icons.

Comment: That's incredible. I couldn't get the lower-resolution icon to work until it was redone at 57px, and now the icons scale.

 [edit]

Actually, that doesn't appear to be working. Is it possible the old icon got cached? Tried overwriting and deleting the app for a clean install, but both times the icon was at the lower resolution.

Comment: @user1958756 In my tests, the iOS device didn't cache the icon, but depending on the environment (webserver/proxy), there may very well be some caching happening. I suggest you rename the file to icon.png and change the plist accordingly.

Comment: That worked. It appears the icons are being cached. I'm also having an issue with .plist files being cached. Perhaps there's a connection? Thanks for your help.